# Rabi as limit of Jaynes-Cummings model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, rabi-model

I was wondering how to get back the Rabi oscillations from the Jaynes-Cummings model.
My first intuition is to let the coupling parameter go to zero, however this does not make the electromagnetic field classical again. How can I get to that?

Answer (score 1):

The electromagnetic field approaches the classical limit when it is described by a coherent state (whereas the particle number states are inherently quantum). Given the sufficiently large mean amplitude of the electromagnetic field, compared to the coupling, whill result in field being weakly affected by the two-level system, in which case it will be effectively a harmonic perturbation, as for a TLS driven by an external field.